# How can I divide users by their user-agent?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3

This divide when it's accessed from iPhone,iPodTouch, and All Androids including iPad.
But, I don't want iPad(and other wide width Tablets) in it!!
How can I exclude iPad(and other wide width Tablets) ?

```
<% if(ua.include?('Mobile') || ua.include?('Android')) %>
    Transaction when it's accessed from iPhone,iPodTouch, and All Androids
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu ?

Comment: Then I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yu should have a look at https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu. It should help you to accomplish things like this.

It also enables you to check in your templates for mobile devices.